# Find and replace string with slash in it and retain the slash in the new string

Tags: regular-expression, substitute, replace, find

I am having a tough time finding and replacing a string using vi.
Source String:

```
&DB2_PORT;/&DB2_DATA;
```

New String after replace:

```
&DB2_PORT;/&DB2_DATA;:tcp=true
```

I can find `&DB2_DATA;` and replace it with `&DB2_DATA;:tcp=true,` but that is not what I need to do.

Can someone please help me understand the appropriate ':s' command in order to achieve this replacement?

Comment: If that's not what you need to do, could you add some more sample data, to make it clearer what it is you're asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
:%s/&DB2_PORT;\/&DB2_DATA;/\0:tcp=true/
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Karl !! It did help, work and save my time too. I always wanted to learn all about this. Is there a good online/book documented you can suggest to gain more knowledge of it ?

Comment: The Vim documentation is good. Start with ":h :s".

Answer (score 3):

As you state, your string contains `/` so presumably that is tripping you up since it must be escaped if you use `/` to delimit the sections of your substitution command. See the other answer here for solution with escaping. But we don't have to use `/` as our separator. We can use any non-alphanumeric, single-byte character except `\`, `"` or `|`. For example, with `#`...

```
:%s#&DB2_PORT;/&DB2_DATA;#&:tcp=true#
```

Note: In a substitution `&` is replaced with whatever string was matched by your pattern.

Comment: Thank you Layer !! This worked too.. Kindly suggest me some good online content I can go through about it..

Regards,
Maneesh Sharma

Comment: @Maneesh, if you're looking for help in general look no further than Vim itself. It has great help files and also has a tutor which, if things are installed properly, you can run from command line with `vimtutor`.  If you want more after the tutorial enter `:help` while in vim and start working your way through the "BASIC" section and then the user manual.

Comment: If you just want help with things like substitution than do `:help usr_10.txt` and you'll read about changing text with substitution, macros, ranges, the awesome 'global' command, and more.